Accuracy of large peptide fragment in LC-MS/MS
Peptide digestion leads to generation of small peptides (ideal) as well as some large peptides (3-4kDa). The large peptides often don't fly well and therefore do not detect well. Does it affect the mass accuracy (delta ppm error) of the detected peptide? I am taking following rationale here: lower peptides are well detected and therefore a high confidence data can be obtained. While in larger peptides that confidence cannot be obtained due to low detection).
